# Adding Full Text Search to my existing Sql Server 2014 installation

Tags: sql-server

I have currently SQL Server 2014 installed on my computer (for testing purpose). I need to add `Full Text Search` functionalities. Then I re-executed the setup but I don't have any Full Text Search Checkbox option on the Feature Selection page (see below).

[image]

Normally Full Text Search should be available on this page as seen on screenshot below (image get from web):

[image]

**So my question is: what do I have to do to add `Full Text Search` to my existing SQL Server 2014 installation ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download SQL Server Express you will find 3 different downloads. They all have different amounts of included features to save on file space as SQL Express is frequently packaged with downloads for third party software.

You need SQL Server 2014 Express **with Advanced Services** for Full Text Search.

The  latest version can be downloaded here [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167)

You will need one of these downloads:

ExpressAdv 32BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe

ExpressAdv 64BIT\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: Thanks I successfully added Full Text Search to my SQL Server database thanks to the version you pointed.